# SQL 2000 script to kill Agent job if it overuns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, sql-server-agent

On a legacy SQL 2000 box that is awaiting upgrade

Does anyone have a script to kill / abort a job in SQL Agent 2000 if it over runs a set duration or overlaps with another agent job.

This is causing us a serious problem every few weeks a job overuns then locks the reindex job and that freezes our 24 / 7 server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to add a step at the beginning of the job with which the long-running job overlaps which checks whether the long-running job is still running, and if it is issue an [`sp_stop_job`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260308%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) command.

You can get the current execution status of a job using [`sp_help_job`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933458%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), but its output is not very easy to manipulate in a query.

Various methods of coercing the output of `sp_help_job` into a temp table in SQL 2000 are discussed [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic259078-8-1.aspx) - alternatively you can query [`msdb.sysjobhistory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260416%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) to get the execution status information.